# Visual studio web

Tags: c#, silverlight

Whats the easiest way to create a web application for tcp server/client or socket?  Ive looked at silverlight but im not sure if thats the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a Web App at the moment is to use Silverlight & RIA Services, but it's typically over http (but binary). If you want to use net.tcp you'll have to build your own custom web services.

With RIA services the trip is to use the "data Sources" window which allows to to customize and drag and drop data straight onto your form.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-NET.TCP-Protocol-in-Silverlight-4.aspx